How to Automatically Rearrange IDs in an SQL Table After Deleting a Row?
I have an SQL table with an id column that uses auto-increment. When I delete a row (e.g., where the id is 6), the IDs of the remaining rows do not change, and there is no longer a row with id 6. How can I automatically rearrange the IDs of the remaining rows so they are continuous (e.g., 1, 2, 3, ... without gaps) after a deletion?
I'm using MySQL.
DO $$
DECLARE
  new_id INTEGER := 1;
BEGIN
  FOR record IN SELECT * FROM your_table ORDER BY id LOOP
    INSERT INTO temp_table (id, column1, column2, ...) 
    VALUES (new_id, record.column1, record.column2, ...);
    new_id := new_id + 1;
  END LOOP;
END $$;

I want alter of this one

How does the posted code relate to your question?

I'm confused why you tagged this postgresql but say you are using MySQL, and also what MySQL error 1064 has to do with your question. Can you clarify or tag more appropriately?

Generally speaking, you should not do this.  The main purpose of a primary key is to durably and uniquely identify a record.  If you change the IDs, it would no longer be a durable (since it changed) or unique (the same ID can refer to different records at different times) ID.  Please explain why you want to do this.  If it's just to look nice (no gaps), I strongly recommend you do not do so.  Further, you may want to read about database design and normalization.

In complex, real systems, separate databases in other software will often refer to IDs in your database.  They wouldn't know about your renumbering.

You don't. IDs are fixed. If you change them, you break everything that refers to them. You should not worry about IDs being sequential, and worry instead about making sure that they're unique.

DON'T DO THIS. Drop this idea Instead, think, how you can facilitate more IDs. i.e. Use datatype like long/bigint instead of int

The table schema is not given.  However, if it is INTEGER (like the script), the MySQL maximum is 2147483647.  That should be sufficient for most tables.  I would consider the pros and cons before using BIGINT, since it could have performance implications.  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.4/en/integer-types.html

This question reminds me of a particular 'manager', that didn't like the gaps in ID's. So, to quell that problem, we simply numbered them sequentially in the application, and he was none the wiser, even though we knew the real ID's.

Rearranging auto-incremented IDs after deletions is bad practice! Normally, auto-increment ID is meant to provide unique, not sequential, identifiers. It is better to accept gaps rather than risk issues with any downstream processing. (You may end up breaking relationships with other tables, negatively impacts performance if you have large tables, etc.).
